# Boulevard usage and parts

Tags: word-choice

I looked up 'boulevard' and got this definition:

"a wide road in a town or city, often with trees along the sides"

My questions:

1. Is this word used for a dual road (in a town or city) that have a line of trees right in the middle to separate traffic lanes? If not, what is the word?
2. What is the word they use to describe that line of trees, or grass that separate the lanes? You can even sit there and watch cars passing you from both sides.

(I've found 'verge' but first it's British and second it's used to describe the edge of a road; also I found 'central reservation' but I'm not quite sure if it works here and it sounds awkwardly formal)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1.** I would say yes.  It is possible that a road with trees down the centre might be named a "Boulevard".  That would not be strange.

**A2.** In most parts of the world (as far as I know), the raised or landscaped section down the centre of a road is called the "median" or "median strip".  In the UK, it is mostly called the "central reservation".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_strip

Answer (score 1):

Originally boulevards were city fortifications that were demolished to create much wider streets. See etymonline http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Boulevard